# Adding Thumbnail Image With CSS Border

Tags: html, css, thumbnails

I am trying to recreate what Lynda.com does with their course listing thumbnail image (see [here](https://www.lynda.com/Developer-training-tutorials/50-0.html)). I am not sure how to place the image inside of my already existing code [here](https://jsbin.com/goteweqiso/1/edit?html,css,output). What I am not sure of is the dimensions of what the image should be each time and I am not sure how to handle the image resizing if my description is really long and widens the border. How would I do this?

If worse comes to worse, I will keep the descriptions small. I also realize that if the image also gets bigger if the description gets longer, the image getting bigger as a side effect will not look consistent with the other thumbnail images on the page.

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"

<a class="course_list_link" href=""> 
<p class = "course_list_border"> 
  <strong> Title </strong> <br/> <br/>    
  description <br/> <br/>  
  skill_level  &emsp; 
  date &emsp; 
  Views: views &emsp; 
subject </p> </a>
```

CSS:

```
.course_list_border{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #DCDCDC;
    padding: 10px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.course_list_border:hover{
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.course_list_link{
    color: black;
}

.course_list_link:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

body {
    min-height: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    margin-top: 0%;
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 55px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16.5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made some changes in your css and HTML file

```css
.course_list_border{
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-color: #DCDCDC;
 padding: 10px;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}

.course_list_border:hover{
 background-color: #F8F8F8;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.course_list_link{
 color: black;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 30%;
}

.course_list_link:hover{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}

body {
 min-height: 400px;
 margin-bottom: 100px;
 margin-top: 0%;
 clear: both;
 padding-top: 55px;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 16.5px;
}
```

```html
<a class="course_list_link" href=""> 
   <p class = "course_list_border"> 
  <strong> Title </strong> <br/> <br/>    
  description <br/> <br/>  
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200X150" alt="Lights" style="width:100%"/>
  skill_level  &emsp; 
  date &emsp; 
  Views: views &emsp; 
   subject </p> 
 </a>
```

As you are using bootstrap you can also make use of existing classes for creating this kind of image thumbnails

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/figures/

Comment: This mostly works but the only problem I am having with it is when I have more or less text inside of a particular course, the course box/border will appear smaller compared to another one next to it where it looks like there is a margin-top. https://imgur.com/a/6gGnKwB. Notice how Intermediate is a longer string than Advanced, which causes the box/border to be smaller. The pagination does not have any margins either. As long as the boxes are the same amount of text, they will appear the same size. Is there a way to use CSS to fix this issue?

Comment: @coimbra See https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/ which is part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it's far better to separate all items into elements, instead of concatenating them into a single paragraph. For example:

```html
<style>
   a.course_list_link {
      display: block;
      width: 300px;
      border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
      border-radius: 5px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      transition: all, 0.3s, ease;
   }
   
   a.course_list_link:hover .thumbnail {
      filter: grayscale(50%);
   }
   
   a.course_list_link:hover {
      background-color: whitesmoke;
   }
   a.course_list_link:active {
      background-color: white;
   }
   
   a.course_list_link:hover p.description {
      color: black !important;
   }

   .course_list_link .thumbnail {
      background-color: grey;
      background-size: cover; /* Guarantees your background always fits the thumbnail size, no matter its aspect ratio */
      height: 150px;
   }
   
   .course_list_link .play-button {
      opacity: 0.5;
      height: inherit;
      width: inherit;
      background-size: 50px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
   }
   .course_list_link:hover .play-button {
      background-image: url('https://www.drury.edu/images/socialmediaicons/play_button.png');
   }

   .course_list_link .content-area {
      margin: 5px;
   }
   
   .course_list_link h2 {
      color: black;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 18px;
      margin: 0;
   }

   .course_list_link p.description {
      margin: 0;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: grey !important;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: -webkit-box;
      -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      color: black;
   }

   .metadata {
      font-size: 12px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-between;
   }
   
   .column {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-between;
   }
   
   .metadata .skill {
      color: grey;
   }
   
   .metadata .date {
      color: grey;
   }
   
   .metadata .views {
      color: grey;
   }
   
   .metadata .subject {
      font-weight: bold;
      color: grey;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
   }
</style>

<a class="course_list_link" href="#">
   <div class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://img-aws.ehowcdn.com/560x560p/photos.demandstudios.com/getty/article/188/230/dv030463.jpg');"><!-- Set the bg image of this element in CSS -->
      <div class="play-button"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="content-area">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p class="description">Description of the video, which may or may not be very long depending on the type of video, and what is chosen to display, and how many lines the space is allowed to occupy in the thumbnail.</p>
      <div class="metadata">
         <div class="column">
            <div class="skill">Skill level</div>
            <div class="views">Views</div>
         </div>
         <div>
            <div class="date">Date</div>
         </div>
         <div>
            <div class="subject">Subject That is Too Long And Will Inevitably Overflow to New Lines If Not Blocked by Some Sort of CSS Trick</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</a>
```

I also like to set the thumbnails in CSS. That way, even if your thumbnail changes size, it is always cropped at the same size within the HTML element. However, it's always good to ensure that images are not oversized so that the page loads quickly; therefore, making real thumbnails is always a good idea.

Just as a side note, it's general CSS good practice to use hyphens instead of underscores, so `.course_list_link` becomes `.course-list-link`.

Comment: I am running into the same problem if I add display:inline-block to a.course_list_link. Also the text flows outside of the border and it is not responsive. https://imgur.com/a/tRiVdJ0 and https://imgur.com/a/HDXa4cj. There could also be many different subjects so having a huge tab in between each subject is not ideal if I make the entire width 100% inside of a.course_list_link. https://imgur.com/a/iwoiktb

Comment: @coimbra I added CSS and modified the HTML so you can see the possibilities. If you want to add `inline-block`, just wrap the video link in another container.

Comment: If there are multiple subjects, you could always add multiple subject lines, or separate them with commas.

Comment: your effort is outstanding. However, I tried some fiddling on my own and got this https://jsfiddle.net/uxbLd3se/. This is a little closer to what I want to accomplish because each course floats left, image is always full size, and it is bootstrap responsive. However, it still has that box sizing problem with too much text. Also, did you remove some stuff from the first example? I loved having the ellipsis for the description being too long. The subjects I will put on its own line but having an ellipsis for that would be good too. Maybe you could help me combine your awesome UX into mine?

Comment: @coimbra The ellipsis is still there. I did make some changes so you could see how to make the thumbnail responsive. Did you go see and understand the link to CSS tricks about ellipsis? It is applied in the  `.subject` class.

Comment: Putting things in a line is always possible. For example, using CSS `.row {display: flexbox;}` and HTML `<div class="metadata"><div class="row"><div class="skill">Skill level</div><div class="views">Views</div><div class="date">Date</div></div>` using `flex-direction: row` or `column` to set whether items stack sideways or vertically. Please read https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Also, using a fixed-size image is always possible by adding the `img` tag and removing the `div.thumbnail` element. I was just demonstrating how you don't need to trim every image before putting it on your page if that's inconvenient.